# Does aws code build support minor versions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html#sample-runtime-update-version) is  example about nodejs versions `8` and `10`, but when I tried to specify

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10.15.0
```

I got en error: `Unknown runtime version named '10.15.0' of nodejs. This build image has the following versions: 10, 8`

So does aws code build supports to specify minor versions?

Answer (score 3):

No. Today, only major versions can be specified for node.js as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html. So for node.js, just use "nodejs: 10". We will improve this experience further by letting customers mention 10.x or just "latest" to pick up the latest LTS version that is pre-configured on the CodeBuild managed image.

Note that we will install the latest minor version of each programming language, as they become available within a few weeks. Current minor version of node on the standard:2.0 Ubuntu image is 10.16 as mentioned in https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/standard/2.0/Dockerfile#L18.

These images have "n" installed on them, so if you need to install the latest (non-LTS) version, say node.js v12, you can simply do an "n latest" or "n version_number" in your buildspec in say a pre_build step.

Comment: This answer seems to contradict what it says in the linked documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html).  Docs say you CAN specify major/minor version.  Check the `How to specify a version in the buildspec file` column where it gives the following examples for node: `nodejs:10.x, nodejs: 12.x`.

Comment: Specifying runtime version as nodejs: 10.x isn't the same as specifying the minor version (e.g.: nodejs: 10.15.0). Documentation is accurate and should be the one to rely on. When I posted the SO answer, we didn't have support for aliasing. This is now rolled out, allowing customers to specify nodejs: 10.x. There are specific programming languages that aren't backwards compatible even with minor versions (PHP, Python, etc.), for these you will be able to specify minor versions explicitly.

Comment: can you elaborate or show an example on how to do "n latest"?

Comment: @SubinMathew I need to specify version 15 of nodeJS and it wouldn't take it. Takes only version 10 and 12. What can be done about that?

Comment: @SubinMathew As of today is there any difference b/w specifying `nodejs: 12` and `nodejs: 12.x`.